# Exponential operator in Python - Giving different result with using variables and with using direct values

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, complex-numbers

We are using exponential operator as below with assigning values to variables:

```
>>> a = -1.5
>>> b = 0.44
>>> c = (a ** b)
>>> c
(0.22397855343551604+1.1741366953411416j)
```

If we use direct values in the exponential operator the result is different:

```
>>> d = (-1.5 ** 0.44)
>>> d
-1.195308902228074
```

We need the second output using the variables.

Comment: Why do you think you need the second one? The first one is *correct*, the second is actually `-(1.5 ** 0.44)`.

Comment: I made this very same mistake in FORTRAN during my PhD work and it cost me no end of pain to debug. I guess there's no way around it: every generation must make the same mistakes as the previous ones.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback. This clears my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `-` has a lower precedence than `**`, so the expression `-1.5 ** 0.44` is actually parsed as if it is `-(1.5 ** 0.44)`.

To get the correct result, you should write `(-1.5) ** 0.44`.

```py
>>> -1.5 ** 0.44
-1.195308902228074
>>> -(1.5 ** 0.44)
-1.195308902228074
>>> (-1.5) ** 0.44
(0.22397855343551604+1.1741366953411416j)
```

The result `-1.195308902228074` is actually incorrect mathematically, but if you really want the *incorrect* result after assigning the numbers to variables, then you can use `abs` and `math.copysign`:

```py
>>> a = -1.5
>>> b = 0.44
>>> import math
>>> math.copysign(abs(a) ** b, a)
-1.195308902228074
```